# Is vim better installed in C:\Program files\

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, desktop-computer

I've installed gVim and the install has gone into here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim`

Would there have been advantages to installing it in the following location?:

`C:\Users\myName\Vim`

Comment: Why do you ask? You don't like the default install location?

Comment: @romainl ...I'm starting to get the feeling that you are quite involved with vim?

Comment: @romainl Calvin cheng's answer in here seemed to suggest installing it in a non-default location: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507476/where-do-i-save-pathogen-vim-so-that-the-plugin-installs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507476/where-do-i-save-pathogen-vim-so-that-the-plugin-installs)

Comment: who marked this question down and why? It is specific but not too wide. It is a proper question. It asks for a definite answer and not opinion. So please tell me why it is marked down?

Answer (score 2):

Vim is not as weird or complicated or mysterious as you seem to believe it is.

You let the installer put Vim and its default runtime wherever it thinks Vim should be installed and customize it by dropping plugins/colorschemes in `$HOME\vimruntime` (`$HOME/.vim` on UNIX-y systems) and setting options in `$HOME\_vimrc` (`$HOME/.vimrc` on UNIX-y systems).

That's all there is to it.

As long as your system knows where the Vim executable is located, you have *no* business messing with that executable and/or its support files: where they are and what they contain is completely irrelevant to you and your configuration effort.

Comment: +1 whoops the `_vimrc` file I have been changing is the one stored in `Program Files`! ....I should just create a copy of `_vimrc` and keep the copy in `$HOME\`, for me `M:\`? The put the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` back to it's default settings? Can I safely put that file back to default settings using vim itself?

Comment: If you can remember what settings are yours yes, you can revert the default `_vimrc` to its pristine state. Make sure you also remove all the plugins and colorschemes you may have installed in the default runtime as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Program Files` is the canonical and recommended place for system-wide software installations on Windows. Especially on "real" multi-user systems (like Unixes), some users may not have sufficient permissions and *have to* do a user-local installation in their home directory, but that's rarely the case on Windows.

Rather, I guess your real question is about installing plugins and configuring Vim. Again, this is not dependent on the Vim installation location, but rather governed by the `'runtimepath'` option. Admittedly, it's complex (and therefore also powerful!) in Vim, but you'll find many resources around this topic (starting with the excellent built-in `:help`).

Comment: +1 again thanks for help Ingo - no need to mention `:help` to me now though as I've found it and am definitely on the learning curve associated with `:help` !